# Trying to make a function to tell is a number is prime or not. What did I do wrong? All my tests pass, but one edabit.com test failed

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

This is the code used to decide whether it's a prime number or not. Please tell me what I did wrong.

```
public class Program
{
    public static bool isPrime(int x)
    {
            int i = 2;

            while (i < x)
            {
                double divided = ((double) x / (double) i);

                if (divided % 1 == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                i++;
            }

            return true;
    }
}
```

Only one of the many tests failed so I'm sure it's some obscure edge case.

Comment: Which test failed?

Comment: `x = 1` is *not* prime, but `isPrime` returns `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, it's a *border case* that fails. In your implementation, it's `1` which is *not prime*, but `isPrime(1)` returns `true`. You can test the routine with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static bool IsIntPrime(int value) {
  if (value <= 1)
    return false;
  else if (value % 2 == 0)
    return value == 2;

  int n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5);

  for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
    if (value % i == 0)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Time to query:

```
  var failedTests = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 100) // let's test [0..99] range
    .Select(x => new {
      x,
      expected = IsIntPrime(x),
      actual = isPrime(x)
    })
    .Where(item => item.actual != item.expected)
    .Select(item => $"{item.x,3} expected: {item.expected,5} actual: {item.actual,5}");

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, failedTests));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 0 expected: False actual:  True
 1 expected: False actual:  True
```

Correction:

```
public static bool isPrime(int x)
{
    // All numbers which are less or equal to 1 are not primes
    if (x <= 1)
        return false; 

    int i = 2;
    ...  
}
```